# How to upload files recursively to OneDrive? i.e. How to upload file structure?

Tags: windows, recursion, onedrive

I understand how to upload a single file/folder to onedrive.

However, I have a bunch of files that I want to upload, and I want to preserve the structure between them.  All of the files/folders are organized in a VERY precise hierarchy on an external SSD, and I want to upload them all at once.

I tried highlighting the top level of the hierarchy and clicking and dragging that to onedrive - no luck.

How do I do this, and have OneDrive copy every subfolder and every file of what I select it to upload?

In CS terms, how do I upload recursively?

Comment: Because you mention "clicking and dragging", I'm led to believe that you are using the software that comes with OneDrive and not writing your own client.  StackOverflow is for programming questions only, you can read the [faq].

Comment: Really sorry if this isn't an SO question.  However, questions directly related to onedrive DO frequently appear elsewhere on SO.  Also, the answer to this question is likely to be programming (hence, the word "recursively").   Any ideas on how to write a script to accomplish this?

Comment: Read [the tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/onedrive/info) for clarification on why some Qs are ok and some aren't.

Comment: In programming terms, the "recursive" part of the question is pretty much trivial.  If you try and get stuck, and can't find an existing answer to help you with your problem, you could post here about it - by that point you'll already know what language you're using and have a better idea of what specific problem you need solved.  In the meantime, if you rephrased this question to ask about the potentially difficult parts - how to upload a file to OneDrive programatically, and how to create a OneDrive folder programatically - that would probably be on-topic, if it hasn't already been answered.